# Input select text but only on first focus (on mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select, focus

So this demo works as expected on desktop
https://stackblitz.com/edit/focus-element?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

"focus" only selects text on first click of input.
"click" selects on every click.

But when testing on iOS it's not behaving the same way...?

Is there some workaround I can use?
I was expecting the `input.focus()` to be invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from a college in the industry... the trick was to use setTimeout

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      input.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
    }, 0);
```